# How do I quickly reorder a Ruby Array given an order?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have an array of values, and an array which determines the order.

How can I quickly re-arrange the array in the given order?

```
data = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']

order = [3,1,2,0,4,5]
```

I want:

```
data = ['3','1','2','0','4','5']
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
data =  ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

order = [3, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5]

> order.map{|x| data[x]}
 => ["3", "1", "2", "0", "4", "5"]
```

**If you are not sure if the indices are correct, you can do this:**

```
> order.map{|x| data.fetch(x)}     # will raise an exception if index out of bounds
 => ["3", "1", "2", "0", "4", "5"]
```

Comment: I use this approach because it allows me to use `fetch` which can raise an exception if it doesn't work.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm thanks for the tip! I ended up using this approach, because I can use exceptions in case an index is out of bounds.

Answer (score 26):

You can use the [`values_at`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/values_at) method written for this kind of task:

```
data = ['0','1','2','3','4','5']
order = [3,1,2,0,4,5]

data.values_at *order
# => ["3", "1", "2", "0", "4", "5"]
```

Comment: neat! why is the * needed in front of order?

Comment: @user985823 Because `values_at` does not take an array as its argument, but an arbitrary number of parameters. The `*` causes each value of the `order` array to be passed as a parameter to the method.

Comment: Great and short answer! But I went with the other solution, because it can raise an exception if an index is wrong. I wish I could mark two questions as correct

Answer (score 5):

Not as good as @Jakub's answer using [`Array#values_at`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-values_at) (which I would argue should be the accepted answer) but here are some other fun alternatives:

```
p data.sort_by.with_index{ |d,i| order[i] }
p data.zip(order).sort_by(&:last).map(&:first)
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, Jakub's and Tilo's method will only work if the numbers in `order' correspond to indices, whereas your second one will work for any `order`.